# Sudden major permalink issues with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks, portfolio

To preface this, all of this functionality was working until a few weeks ago. I have a wordpress site with postname permalinks. Have had this since day 1 and its worked out well until recently.

It's related to portfolios and wordpress (3.4.2).

Suddenly (perhaps after some recent plugin update or change in wind direction:) ) I started getting 404s on all my portfolio 'items'.

Portfolio list (page) works ok. Such as http://www.dasilvamotorsport.com/performance-project-portfolio/

I switched permalinks to default (numeric). And suddenly portfolio items like the below started showing:
http://www.dasilvamotorsport.com/portfolio-item/honda-nsx/

But portfolio category doesn't show:
http://www.dasilvamotorsport.com/performance-project-portfolio/

Switching back to postname as permalink basically reverts back to the original issue that portfolio items don't show up. I had heard that permalinks may need a refresh but this hasn't helped me. I've refreshed a dozen times, restarted the server, checked and double checked .htaccess to no avail.

Again, all of this was working perfectly until a couple of weeks ago so really not sure what happened. Is there something I can debug or try? I've tried WP_DEBUG but for some reason the debug.log file is never created so not sure what's going on there. (Yes, I've tried wp_debug_log parameter also).

No errors relating to this in the apache error log.

Appreciate any help on this.

I have been running this on a ubuntu 11.10 box, with apache2 and varnish cache as a front end. Nothing has changed in terms of infrastructure since day 1 when it worked.

Comment: As a side note due to the hurricane my data center is currently experiencing some connectivity issues so site may be extremely slow but will load.

Answer (score 0):

first of all category link you mentioned is not the correct category link, it must be as

http://www.dasilvamotorsport.com/category/performance-project-portfolio/
which is by default.

2nd go to the permalink structure and use the default structure and save them check if is it working correct ?
if yes then again select the %postname% and save,
last you can also try by deactivating all your plugins then check if all the things working fine, after deactivation of plugins then try to reactivate plugins 1 by 1 , so that you can find, if there is any bug in any of the plugins that is making conflict with the permalinks.
thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried permalink refreshes as mentioned above. With default it works (except for the default category page) i.e. portfolio items are working, switching back to postname breaks portfolio items again. I haven't setup a base category so my links show without category. This has worked so far.

Comment: OK, made some progress. Default permalink it works, ANY other permalink structure breaks portfolio items. It actually worked correctly for about 5 minutes with postname then back to 404s. Completely stumped here. Anyone with suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked it after deactivation of all your plugins ? if it works then there may be a bug in any of the plugins.
then reactivate them 1 by 1, so that you can find the exact faulty plugin,
thanks,

Comment: Yep, deactivated everything almost and no change. I'm wondering if a duplicate would do this of some sort.